# Laravel 8 relations with multiples tables

Tags: laravel, eloquent

I work on a web application for a car repairer.

In my application, an user can create an **Intervention**. An **Intervention** can have one or multiple **Operation(s)**. An **Operation** can have one or multiple **Piece(s)**. An **Intervention** have 1 **Car**.

Example :  (**Numbers** = **ID**)

- Intervention **1**

  - Car **18**
  - Operation **1**

    - piece **7**
    - piece **12**
  - Operation **2**

    - piece **4**
    - piece **8**
- Intervention **2**

  - Car **12**
  - Operation **5**

    - Piece **4**
    - Piece **6**

Here are my tables :

| Intervention | Operation | Piece | Car |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| id | id | id | id |
| car_id | name | name | numberplate |

I don't know which type of **relations** to use in my models ( **Intervention** , **Operation** , **Piece**).

In my **Intervention view** I need to display :

- All **operations** affected to this **intervention**.
- All **pieces** affected to an **operation**.

I need help to make the good type of relations in my models.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can try this in the model file (Intervention, Operation, Piece).

Intervention Model

```
public function operation()
{
    return $this->hasMany(Operation::class);
}
```

Operation Model

```
public function intervention()
{
    return $this->belongsTo(Intervention::class);
}


public function piece()
{
    return $this->hasMany(Piece::class);
}
```

Piece Model

```
public function operation()
{
    return $this->belongsTo(Operation::class);
}
```

If you want to set up your own foreign_key you can read the documentation https://laravel.com/docs/8.x/eloquent-relationships

Answer (score 0):

You can use laravel's document on this:

[Eloquent Relationships](https://laravel.com/docs/8.x/eloquent-relationships)

Comment: Thanks for ur answer but I need help on how to organize my models.

Answer (score 0):

you can use this for relation, your relation in array parameter of with method and if you need check has relation you can use whereHas function

```
Operator::with(['piece'])->get();
```